# Batch Geocode Postcodes/Addresses in UTM

Tags: batch, utm, geocoding

My work has a database of previous jobs (within housing plots) which are meant to have been georefernced with UTM coordinates, but this has not been completed for a number of years. New jobs can use data from old ones, and there is a facility in the database to check for properties within a certain radius of the new job using UTM coordinates.

I have batch georeferenced addresses using Lat Long before using sites like GPS Visualizer, but cannot find a means to georeference in UTM, and converting lat long to UTM seems difficult.

Does anyone know of a site which will help me do this, or know of a site which will convert directly to UTM coordinates?

The UTM Zone is 17N (Winnipeg).

Comment: http://www.geoplaner.com/ will convert single UTM-17N addresses

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176137/java-convert-lat-lon-to-utm

Although you didn't say if you want a solution to do it in Java, .Net or via a web service...

If you need a service to geocode address, try Nominatim:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Comment: Its a one time requirement, or perhaps something to be done once every 6 months or something - Once I have the coordinates, I will input in to the database and hopefully from there people will input them as they create new jobs. Cheers for the links, will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the response, this is what I ended up doing:

I used GPS Visualizer's batch geocoder to provide Lat Long for the 4k addresses, using an API key from Google (I used mapquest first, but the results were consistently out of place - Google appears to be spot on). Strangely, the site states that Google's policies do not allow the results to be displayed as text, but if you click on the "more options" link once the geocoding has completed, it gives you the information anyway...

I then signed up to a months access to Earth Point ($5) and it instantly transferred my results to UTM.

Jobs a goodun!